# xml POST with RestSharp

Tags: xml, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to POST the following:

```
POST API/storage
Content-Type: application/xml
<StorageDocument xmlns="http://xml.somename.com/schema/somename">
  <type>LOCAL</type>
  <method>
    <uri>file:///path/to/files/</uri>
    <read>true</read>
    <write>true</write>
    <browse>true</browse>
    <type>NONE</type>
 </method>
 <autoDetect>true</autoDetect>
</StorageDocument>
```

My code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();

        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(baseUrlString);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin", "admin");

        var request = new RestRequest("API/storage", Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter ("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

        string xml =
            "<StorageDocument xmlns=\"http://xml.somename.com/schema/somename\">" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<type>LOCAL</type>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<method>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<uri>file:///path/to/files/</uri>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<read>true</read>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<write>true</write>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<browse>true</browse>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<type>NONE</type>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</method>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<autoDetect>true</autoDetect>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</StorageDocument>";


        request.AddBody(xml);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(response.Content));
    }
```

When I post I get "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type". I have tried many things but cannot figure out where is the issue. I believe it is with xml or body of the request but cannot find the solution.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

It could be useful for someone in my situation, this code worked

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();

        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(baseUrlString);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin", "admin");


        var request = new RestRequest("API/storage", Method.POST);


        string rawXml = "<StorageDocument xmlns=\"http://xml.somename.com/schema/somename\"><type>LOCAL</type><method><uri>file://home/Testuser/storage/</uri><read>true</read><write>true</write><browse>true</browse><type>NONE</type></method><autoDetect>true</autoDetect></StorageDocument>";

        request.AddParameter("application/xml", rawXml, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(response.Content));
    }
```

The key point is to use AddParameter instead of AddBody, mentioned here
[RestSharp PUT XML, RestSharp is sending it as GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193918/restsharp-put-xml-restsharp-is-sending-it-as-get?rq=1)
by Richard Friend

Comment: You Save me! Thank You!

Comment: guys, how to add to this code a fileStream. For example, I have a row in my xml <FileStream>cid:123456</FileStream>, and I select in my SOAP UI an attachment with Part = 123456. Can I add this filestream in C#? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This might help someone... this worked for me

```
        var postUrl = "https://your-api.com/resource/path";
        string rawXml = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";

        IRestClient client = new RestClient();
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = postUrl
        };

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        request.AddParameter("text/xml", rawXml, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = client.Post<Note>(request);

        Assert.IsNotNull(response.Data);
```

Comment: Thank you. This got me where I needed to be. I also had to overwrite the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback to always be true, for the time being.